# Unitarity and Vector Space relation

Tags: vectors

Can an operator be a unitary operator in a vector space and not be a unitary operator in another? If so, can I have a simple example or can anyone tell me when does that happen?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the operator
\begin{equation*}
O = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

is unitary in the complex vector space spanned by $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(0, 1, 0)$, but not unitary in $\mathbb{C}^3$.